# Can't combine text and formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I get a compilation error but it's well written I think ...

`RangeBb.Formula "=Fait le '" & TODAY() & "' à Saint-Cyr-L'École,"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I get when I enter this inside a cell and record the macro:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""Fait le"" & TODAY() & ""ici"""
```

Answer (score 3):

```
RangeBb.Formula = "=""Fait le "" & TEXT(TODAY(), ""dd.mm.yyyy"") & "" a Saint-Cyr-L'Ecole,"""
```

Note that you need to wrap `TODAY()` in `TEXT()` in order to display the date properly.

The formula will be:

`="Fait le " & TEXT(TODAY(), "dd.mm.yyyy") & " a Saint-Cyr-L'Ecole,"`

and the display text in the cell:

`Fait le 09.02.2023 a Saint-Cyr-L'Ecole,`